# clang: Remove comments in preprocessed files?

Tags: clang, llvm

is there a way to tell clang to remove comment lines when generating preprocessed output?

Apparently, this is a difference between gcc and clang, and I have not found an option to do so

Thanks

Alex

To be more precise: It seems that I have an issue with input from file, please see this sample:
`CONTENT="// \$REMOVE BEFORE FLIGHT\$\r\nprintf(\"HelloWorld!\");"
echo "Original:\n$CONTENT"
echo "-------------------------"
echo "From stdin"
echo $CONTENT | cpp -P -E -nostdinc -xc++ -
echo "-------------------------"
echo "From file"
echo $CONTENT > foo.sample
cpp -P -E -nostdinc -xc++ foo.sample
echo "\n What gives?"`

**Addition:** It appears, that the `-x` Argument is changed. Using -v, I can see that on the command line, actually `-x c++` is passed, whereas when using a file as input, it is changed to `-x c`.

Any idea why?